# Don't need to delete VM and save money at windows azure

Tags: azure

I want to save money at windows azure.
I created multiple VMs and just use them 1 days per month. I don't want to cost money at another 29 days each month. I hate to delete them and re-create them again.
I just want to stop them and don't delete them while I don't use.

My question is,

1. if I just stop them and don't delete them, will Microsoft azure cost
   my money?
2. Seems while creating a vm, it will automatically create a cloud
   service and disk, How can I avoid cost while I stop my VM?

I have searched, no direct answer, can anyone answer me and provide a link?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you stop/de-allocate a Virtual Machine from the Management Portal, Windows Azure will no longer charge for compute but you will be charged only for the storage of the Virtual Hard Disk + Data Disks (If any). (Ref: http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/06/19/windows-azure-virtual-machines-there-s-more-than-1-way-to-shutdown-a-vm.aspx)

The amount charged will further depend on type of Storage Account (Locally redundant, Geo-Redundant, Read Access Geo Redundant), the below link will help you find out Total cost of ownership.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=data-management

Please note that VMs external IPs (Virtual IPs) are subject to change if de-allocated and started again.

Comment: Should I also stop cloud service too? Or just stop VM is enough?

Comment: Cloud Service is just a logical container\namespace for one or more cloud resources. If your Cloud service has only one VM, stopping either the cloud service or the VM mean one and the same. But if your VMs are grouped under a single cloud service, stopping a cloud service will shutdown all the VMs, in such cases if you want to shut down an individual VM you should shut down from Virtual Machines section using Stop VM action.